# Split pane to cwd

Tags: iterm2

I often want to start a persistent process from a particular directory and be able to monitor it, while still keeping a command line in that directory for other commands.  My current workflow is to `cmd + shift + d` to split panes, but the cwd of the new pane is back at home, and I need to cd back to where I was.  Is there a good way to split panes and automatically set cwd of the new pane to the same directory as the pane it was split from?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

lanVS's solution works out, but there may be a side effect that you don't want:
If you open new tab/windows, it will reuse previous session's directory.

So if you just want the new split pane to act like that, you can do that:

1. open "Preferences", select "Profiles"
2. select the profile you want to change
3. go to "General" subtab
4. set Working Directory to "Advanced Configuration"
5. click "Edit..."
6. select "Reuse previous session's directory" for option "Working Directory for New Split Panes"

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer from http://teohm.com/blog/2012/03/22/working-effectively-with-iterm2/:

> **Open tab/pane with current working directory**
>
> Under Profiles tab, go to General subtab, set Working Directory to “Reuse previous session’s directory”.